# Amazon SES using PHP SDK doesn't work?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, web-hosting, aws-sdk

I've been trying to send emails using Amazon SES SDK with PHP and since I've switched hosts this doesn't work. 
Here's my script:

```
$usrMessage = 'hello, just testing';
$usrTo = 'test@test.com';

//Amazon SES - Getting the client ready
require 'amazon/aws.phar';
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;
error_reporting(1);
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$client = SesClient::factory(array(
  'key'    => '[private]',
  'secret' => '[private]',
  'region' => 'eu-west-1'
));
//End of Amazon SES

$msg = array();
$msg['Source'] = "Test <test@test.com>";
//ToAddresses must be an array
$msg['Destination']['ToAddresses'][] = $usrTo;
$msg['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = "Download Link for your Freebie";
$msg['Message']['Subject']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";
$msg['Message']['Body']['Text']['Data'] ="Text data of email";
$msg['Message']['Body']['Text']['Charset'] = "UTF-8";
$msg['Message']['Body']['Html']['Data'] = $usrMessage;
$msg['Message']['Body']['Html']['Charset'] = "UTF-8"; 
$result = $client->sendEmail($msg);   
//End of Amazon SES Script
```

As I mentioned, this works fine on localhost and on my old hosting account but it doesn't work on the servers of my new hosting provider. The script doesn't work and no error report is shown, just a blank page...

I tried to echo a line after the second comment but it doesn't show up anything so I suppose it's an issue when requesting the aws.phar (the file is present in the appropriate folder)

I think it might be an issue on the webhosting company's side, does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: sounds like you error checking\display off. thats why you get a blank screen. add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: I'd start by checking PHP version differences between your local dev env vs your hosting provider. Also, check any error logs provided by your hosting.

Comment: @nogad I added those lines in place of `error_reporting(1);
@ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and I still get a blank page...

Comment: @JonStirling My previous host (the one that worked) ran php 5.4.45 and the current one is 5.4.37. I don't know if there's such a big difference between the 2.

Comment: @JonStirling It looks like the problem was the PHP version indeed, I switched it to 7.0 from cPanel and it now works. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue was an old PHP version. If anyone experiences this, simply go into cPanel -> "Select PHP Version" and switch your PHP version to a newer one and select all the necessary extensions. I switched to PHP 7.0 and this now works fine.